# ActiveRecord enum behaviour change in rails 6.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am in the process of upgrading from 6.0.3 to 6.1.4. Once thing I noticed after the upgrade is that, enum attributes are no longer returning the keys. Its returning the actual value in the database.

eg:

```
  enum onboard_variation: {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    key3: "value3"
  }
```

In the console

Rails 6.0.3

```
Account.first.onboard_variation => "key1"
```

Rails 6.1.4

```
Account.first.onboard_variation => "value1"
```

I went through the entire release notes and there is not mention of this change. What could be contributing to this?

Comment: What does printing `Account.onboard_variation` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was. We had a custom default definition like below

```
attribute :onboard_variation, :string, default: -> { Utilities::Random.flip_coin ? "value1" : "value2" }
```

Rails 6.1 supports defaults on the enum definition. Changed to below and everything works as expected

```
enum onboard_variation: {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2",
        key3: "value3"
      }, _default: -> { Utilities::Random.flip_coin ? "value1" : "value2" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that issue is, when you define default enum value using `attribute`.

```
  enum status: {
    created: 0,
    proceed: 1
  }

  attribute :status, :integer, default: :created
```

to

```
  enum status: {
    created: 0,
    proceed: 1
  }, _default: "created"

  # remove attribute
```